# Correct Database Architecture

Tags: database, database-design

I don't know how to design my mysql webdatabase for a shop.

The scenario is for a site selling guided tours.

Each tour can be either a Private, a Semi-Private or a Group Tour.  The price per person changes per tour type.  BUT ALSO for the Private tours, the price per person varies depending on the number of persons.  However it varies by different amounts depending on tour.  How would i create a 'Tour/Product' record?

e.g.  Let's say:

Tour of Vatican (tour has various bits of data - name, description, meeting point, duration, etc).  Semi-Private tour costs 50 euro per person.  Group tour costs 45 euro per person.  Private tour costs (140 euro for 1-2 people), or 180 euro for 3 people, or 200 euros for 4 people, or 225 euros for 5 people or 240 euro for 6 people or for 7 people or more it costs 43 euro per person.
HOWEVER for the Tour of Coliseum (tour has same bits of data - name, description, meeting point, duration, etc), Semi Private costs 40 per person.  Group costs 25 per person.  Private tour costs (100 euro for 1-2 people), or 135 euro for 3 people, or 160 euros for 4 people, or 175 euros for 5 people or 180 euro for 6 people or for 7 people or more it costs 25 euro per person.

How would i structure the data in the database - 2 tables? 3 tables?

Totally confused....

Thanks

Tom

Comment: You probably want a rules engine here, like Drools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your post, the price alters depending on three different things:

1. The tour: the price for the Tour of Vatican is not similar with the price for the Tour of Colloseum.
2. The type of the tour: Private, a Semi-Private or a Group Tour.
3. The number of persons on the tour.

Since there is no exact (constant) price per person on any of the given options, I would go for a three tables approach.

The digaram is detailed in the below picture and works under the following assumptions:

- There are three tables: **Tour** (containing the description for each individual tour); **TourPriceOptions** (containing the individual price options records) and **TourType** (which at all times, will contain just three records: Private, Semi-Private and Group Tour);
- There are just two assumptions that you have to do:

  - A tour can have multiple price options (1 to many relationship)
  - An price option can have just one single tour type (1 to 1 relationship)

**How to code this up:**

- Whenever the administrator of the store creates another tour in the backend of the store, he should be able to add multiple price options. In order to do this you will need to:

  - **Create a new tour:** a function which inserts in to the database a new entry in the tour table.
  - **Get the id of the recently created tour:** if there is only one person adding information at any given time, then there is a good bet to write a function that returns the id of the latest added tour.
  - **Add pricing options based on the id_tour:**  insert a new price option based on the id_tour variable. Remember to assign a tour_type from one of the already predefined categories.
- Whenever you want to return these values, just write a query that allows you to retrieve information based on the tour the user is currently browsing.

*Additional things to research: **Dynamic Forms** - They will help you when you don't know how many price options an admin might want to add for a specific tour*

[image: ERR diagram of the database]